# Derivation of $B$ field and $E$ field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

For an infinite plate of charge, the E field is (density of charge per area) divided by (2*vacuum permittivity). In deriving it, we used Gauss' Law and say that the flux through the two ends of the Gaussian surface has similar contribution (and thus we divide it by 2).

For a solenoid, we use Ampere's Law and assume that one end is so far away that the contribution of B-field is zero. Thus, B field inside solenoid is (vacuum permeability*I*N)/L.

Why didn't we assume that the one end of the Gaussian surface is so far away and thus the E-field contribution is zero (and thus we didn't have to divide by 2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an argument that the relevant field actually diminishes as you go toward spatial infinity.  Often this step is omitted when working with the solenoid, although it can be demonstrated without too much trouble.  The problem with doing the same for Gauss's Law with an infinite sheet of charge is that the electric field does not get any weaker as you go to spatial infinity.  So no matter how far away you put one end of your Gaussian pillbox, the electric flux through then end is always the same.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of electric field and Gauss’ law, a key part of the argument is that the ends of the Gaussian box are *symmetrically* placed at the same distance from the plane, thus guaranteeing by symmetry that the flux through both ends is the same.  Thus, whatever the size of the box, the net total flux will be twice the flux at one end.

If the ends are each at a different distance from the plane, there is indeed no *a priori* guarantee the flux through each is the same.